# Tensorflow, movie reviews predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make the following tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data,
                                                        value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                        padding='post',
                                                        maxlen=256)

test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data,
                                                       value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                       padding='post',
                                                       maxlen=256)

vocab_size = 10000

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


prediction = model.predict(test_data[5])
print(prediction)
```

Why does the prediction return an array of 256? And not 0 or 1? How to do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same train and test data as the tutorial? Can you share your model summary?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to pass list of numpy arrays, as far as I remember

Try something like:

```
model.predict(np.array([test_data[5]]))
```

Does it what you expected?
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it does not work (same return)

Comment: my bad, try to pass numpy array model.predict(np.array([test_data[5]])) should works, also don't forget to call model.fit to train your model :)